# How can I set a 'global' Exposed filter rewrite for taxonomy terms on a view

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

How would I go about settings a rewrite for display taxonomy (Rewrite filter options), but as a 'global', instead of having to set each individual value for exposed filter?

I can see the there is place to add individual value overrides for the filter display, but my taxonomies are many and may update occasionally.

So the issue is two-fold; The taxonomies to be displayed on the exposed filter are quite long in some cases (which is needed). And they will be adjusted on the fly by content maintainers.

Instead of:
1 | Display 1
2 | Display 2
3 | Display 3

I would be perfect if I can do:

`[vocabulary:original:name]|[vocabulary:original:description]`

But for some reason it's not working for me.

The additional application of this is that the short tax term can be used on the csv import, but front-end displays the complete long version tax.

So if I can get the actual term to be a 'keyword' and display to front-end users a long term, the back-end user will have a better experience as well.

Currently working with Better Exposed Filters and D7.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a excellent module [Token formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_formatters). Can be used in various places, but for this application it's spot on.

Once installed, the formatter for a entity reference field on a view gets and addition in the dropdown 'Tokenized Text'. That in turn allow for a a wider range of token us. [see all your tokens at Admin -> Help -> Token ].

Drop the Token of your choice and swap out between fields or Taxonomies.

In my case I has an additional field on my Taxonomy terms. All the regular places I tried to reference it only gave termID or termLabel as options. Now I can use the build in features of taxonomy terms, but on one of their custom text fields.